# Pandas.read_csv ParserError '§' expected after '"' with sep = "§"

Tags: python, pandas, parse-error, read-csv

I have an issue with `read_csv` and its taking a lot of time to resolve.

I am working with texts which have multiple special characters, so I was checking which character isn't in the list of texts and chose § as delimiter while writing the `csv` files that separates the texts with corresponding IDs.

However, while reading the files, I am getting the following error. I could skip the bad lines, but in this case I cannot afford to lose any texts.

`ParserError: '§' expected after '"'`

Writing

```
df.to_csv('20231010.csv',
           index=False,
           sep='§',
           #header=None,
           quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
           quotechar="",
           escapechar=" ")
```

Reading

```
data = pd.read_csv('20231010.csv',  sep ="§", encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the file that triggers the error

Comment: Also, why would you disable quoting in the export? You can actually use a character that is in the text, you just need to correctly escape it. This happens all the time with the default `,`

Comment: I would have, If I would know what triggers the error. I have 40K texts in the data.frame.

Comment: If all you are doing with the `csv` is reading it back into a dataframe later, have you considered using any other data format, eg pickle (which pandas natively support via `to_pickle` and `read_pickle`) ?

Comment: @mozway then i am not aware of how to escape it correctly, can you please give me more insights? Thanks

Comment: @DeepSpace That's a good idea! it didn't come to my mind. However, some people want to give a quick look into the texts using notepad++.

Comment: @sveer just keep the defaults, CSV can escape characters, see below. ["*if it ain't broke, don't fix it*"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to disable quoting, and actually you don't even need to use a fancy character, just use the default settings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text1': ['abc"123§', 'def ,456'],
                   'text2': ['ghi`789', 'jkl|123'],
                  })

df.to_csv('20231010.csv', index=False)
```

CSV:

```
text1,text2
"abc""123§",ghi`789
"def ,456",jkl|123
```

Importing again:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('20231010.csv')
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
      text1    text2
0  abc"123§  ghi`789
1  def ,456  jkl|123
```

Pandas can relatively well import/export a CSV file without changes. The most common things that could cause a change are:

- the default inclusion of the index in `to_csv`, which gets converted to column by `read_csv`
- conversion of specific strings to NaN (e.g. `NULL`/`NA`), which can be annoying if those strings have a different meaning in your context

You can avoid theses issues by using `index=False` in [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) (as you did), and `keep_default_na=False` in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).